# Layered navigation - multiple attribute choices

Tags: category, layered-navigation

I'd like to make a simple "multiple choices per attribute" addon for the layered navigation.

Simply put, I want

```
/pisarniska-razsvetljava.html?led_color[]=3&led_color[]=4
```

to work. For this to happen, I need to

1. convert attribute keys into IDs (e.g. led_color -> ID #2)
2. alter the product collection load procedure to handle attribute value arrays and not just plain values

Because I can't see any of that happening in Mage/Catalog/CategoryController, where would I go or which class/method would I need to overload?

I found this repo https://github.com/mercator/catalin_seo which does what we want but it's very difficult to make any sense of it as the author overloads a ton of classes. I am hoping for a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to rewrite
`app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php`
to generate right urls  and
`app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php`
plus
`app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Layer\Filter\Attribute.php`
to accept multiple values filter.

As well as `app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Block\Layer\State.php` to show the selection.

Make sure it will work with the search, as it uses different layer collection.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll try it Monday morning and get back to you.

Comment: I finally got back to this task and yes this was all I needed :) Thank you

Comment: @OmerSabic i've got the same problem, i know it's not correct for the forum policy, but can you share your solution?

Comment: @krybbio sorry mate, this was 3 years ago at an agency where I do not work  any more, so I don't have the source. Just check those classes and overload the correct methods, if you have some PHP experience you'll manage it.