# Layered navigation - multiple attribute choices in magento not working

Tags: magento-1.9

I need multiple choices filter result in Layered Navigation.
I have tried this link
[Layered navigation - multiple attribute choices](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34050/layered-navigation-multiple-attribute-choices/)

But I cant change the getUrl() method in app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Layer\Filter\Item.php

I need to pass multi attributes like this http://192.168.1.63/project/index.php/mobiles.html?product_country=4457&product_country=4459

Anyone please suggest? Can anyone explain in detail, Can anyone give that code, where I need to change?

Comment: Check here http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/1293/select-more-than-one-item-in-layered-navigation-multiple-select-checkboxes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this extension to enable multiple attribute choice functionality

http://www.manadev.com/advanced-layered-navigation-ce

After installing this extension **clear cache**

Hope it helps you

Comment: Yes I saw that extension, If can we do manually to achieve that?

Comment: Yes we can also do manually. But this extension is free. you can use it

Comment: okay, If you know, how to do manual means please let me know.Thanks for your response.

Comment: You can check it by downloading this extension and check it's code how they manage this

Comment: I have installed that package, but In layered navigation attributes are not displayed.It shows empty.

Comment: Did you checked their demo, Admin setting etc? Also enable error log and check what error is coming

Comment: Yes I have checked their demo, and I did like that only, But it shows empty.Do u know any solution for that?

Comment: Check your error log. is there any error?

Comment: Now its ok, Its coming, After Cache clear, its working.